# pdo connection error

Tags: pdo

```
<?php
$config['db'] = array (
'host'                  =>  'localhost'
'username'                  =>  'root'
'password'                  =>  ''  
'dbname'                    =>  'phplogin'
);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['db']['host']};dbname={$config['db']['dbname']}",
          $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);


?>
```

receives error:  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''username'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\webroot\wamp\www\index.php on line 4"

My question is: 
Can you *highlight* or comment on the lines I have to insert **my** information such as localhost, databasename, table, root, "",  etc.  Also if you see any changes that need to be made.

Answer (score 1):

When you get errors, you can find the mistake by looking in the error message
The T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING parser token error occurs due to an unexpected quote, so all you had to do is look at your code to notice that you don't have commas in the array declaration as stated by Johnny000. You always have to look the error messages and interpret their meaning. That's coding 101 in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you forget to seperate the arrayvalues with `,`

Here the right code

```
<?php
$config['db'] = array (
'host'                      =>  'YOURHOST',
'username'                  =>  'YOURUSERNAME',
'password'                  =>  'YOURPASSWORD',
'dbname'                    =>  'YOURTABLE'
);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['db']['host']};dbname={$config['db']['dbname']}",
          $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);


?>
```